# Does the .Net Mono project support the iPad?

Tags: mono, intellipad

I hear the mono project (for allowing .net apps to run on many O/Ss) has come a long way (Winforms support, etc.)

Does it (or are there plans for it to) support porting to the iPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it does not appear to be free (or cheap): [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/)